# How to share data between ExtJS grids

Tags: perl, extjs

I am working with a PERL Miner::Base and JavaScript platform (.pm and .js).
My JavaScript contains 3 ExtJS GridPanels.

Now, here's my problem:

I have a function that takes ~1 minute to run and returns a list with references to the data needed for **all** 3 grids. Let's call this function "foo".

Currently, in order to load each of my grids' store, I call a function that calls "foo" and returns only the relevant reference out of the list returned by "foo".

I need **a way to call "foo" only once** and share the data it returns between my 3 stores.

Is there such a way?

Thanks.

Here is the basic structure of my code:

```
my_code.js:
gridA with storeA (calls my_code.pm::get_A_data)
gridB with storeB (calls my_code.pm::get_B_data)
gridC with storeC (calls my_code.pm::get_C_data)


my_code.pm:
get_A_data (calls foo and returns the first reference returned from foo)
get_B_data (calls foo and returns the second reference returned from foo)
get_C_data (calls foo and returns the third reference returned from foo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have three grids you effectively would need to have three stores. However you can do one request, get a store object and then clone it into other two local copies. Search for `cloning ExtJs store`